# Example on discontinuous derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals, continuity

Apart from the function $$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr}
x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & x\neq 0\\
0 & x = 0
\end{array}
\right.$$are there any other elementary functions which have discontinuous derivative.  Since $f'(0)=0$ so shouldn't it mean that $f'(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$.

I attempted to make an elementary function myself and am not sure whether it is appropriate. It goes like this: $$F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$$ where $$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr}
x+1 & 0 \leq x <1\\
x+2 & 1\leq x \leq 2
\end{array}
\right.$$
Clearly $F'(x)=f(x)$ so derivative exists at $x=1$ but derivative is not continuous at $x=1$.

Please let me know whether the latter example is correct.

Comment: How does the derivative exist at $x=1$?

Comment: Calculating derivative by first principles does give different derivatives on left hand side and right hand side but can we use $F'(x)= f(x)$ directly which will give $F'(1)=f(1)=3$.

Comment: For differentiability, FTOC requires that the integrand is continuous.

Comment: Will it not do if $f(x)$ were to be just monotonic

Comment: What is your definition of "elementary function"?